# Automatic Login into a different website and run this website in iframe on my website page?

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a page in my website there are different links on my page for different websites to login. I want to login into the different website by clicking the link and the response website display in an iframe on my website page. Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give yours links a target as the *iframe* you want the app to open in?